Solaris 10 elfsign: how to create a correct certificate to sign a binary?
On Solaris11 is possible to use certificates made with openssl, on Solaris 10 is different
elfsign sign -c solaris10.crt -k solaris10.key -e libeel-2.so 

exit with error and state of exit is 4 (certificate not loaded)
anyone know how to create a certificate in pkcs#10 format for this program?
PEM trying
I tryng a pem certificate...but give error.
elfsign sign -c sol1.pem -k sol1.pem -e libeel-2.so 
elfsign: Unable to load certificate: sol1.pem

Generating a pem with those commands works..but now don't load the key
openssl req -config ssl/openssl.cnf -new -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout snakeoil.key -out snakeoil.csr -batch
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in snakeoil.csr -signkey snakeoil.key -out snakeoil.pem


elfsign sign -c snakeoil.pem -k snakeoil.key -e libeel-2.so 
elfsign: Unable to load private key: snakeoil.key


Isn't PKCS 10 for CSRs, not Certs?

Also, what format is your cert in?  Man page indicates it accepts the BER binary encoding instead of the more common DER, so it would be better to use the "PEM" encoding to be compatible with other tools.

I will try now the "ber" binary and I put the result in the question

I cannot found a way to generate a "ber" certificate, I try the pem

Actually pem failed

To explain better:  DER (really ASN.1 distinguished encoding rules) and PEM (stands for Privacy Enhanced Mail for legacy reasons) are two ways to encode cryptographic structures, as binary data in a fixed format and as a base64 encoding with header and footer lines respectively.  A PEM file is basically a DER file encoded in base64 with a fixed column width and those '-----BEGIN X509 CERTIFICATE----' header and footer lines attached.  BER is the ASN.1 Basic Encoding Rules, which is like DER except there can be multiple ways of expressing the same structure (which is bad for signatures)
